# Overwrite CartController and OnepageController

Tags: magento, overwrite

I try to overwrite 2 controllers in one module. These are both Checkout controllers. 
- OnepageController
- CartController

My cart controller works. But mine onepage controller does not overwrite. Can it be that you can not overwrite 2 files?

My files:

**WP/Ajaxcart/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
       <WP_Ajaxcart>
           <version>0.1.0</version>
       </WP_Ajaxcart>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <checkout>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <WP_Ajaxcart before="Mage_Checkout">WP_Ajaxcart</WP_Ajaxcart>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </checkout>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**WP/Ajaxcart/controllers/OnepageController.php**

```
<?php

require_once "Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php";
class WP_Ajaxcart_Checkout_OnepageController extends Mage_Checkout_OnepageController
{

    public function successAction()
    {

        $session = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout();

        if (!$session->getLastSuccessQuoteId()) {
           $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
            return;
        }

        $lastQuoteId = $session->getLastQuoteId();
        $lastOrderId = $session->getLastOrderId();
        $lastRecurringProfiles = $session->getLastRecurringProfileIds();
        if (!$lastQuoteId || (!$lastOrderId && empty($lastRecurringProfiles))) {
            $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
            return;
        }
        echo 'Do something else';
        //$session->clear();
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session');
        Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_onepage_controller_success_action', array('order_ids' => array($lastOrderId)));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

}
```

**WP/Ajaxcart/controllers/CartController.php**

```
<?php

require_once "Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php";
class WP_Ajaxcart_Checkout_CartController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController
{

    public function addAction()
    {
        echo 'test';
    }

}
```

I has someone any idea what doing wrong why it's not overwriting the OnepageController.php.

Thank you.

Lex

Comment: Are the file locate exactly in `WP/Ajaxcart/controllers/OnepageController.php`? If is, move to `WP/Ajaxcart/controllers/Checkout/OnepageController.php`

Comment: Mistype, but still it is not working. I have the edit the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
<WP_Ajaxcart_Checkout before="Mage_Checkout">WP_Ajaxcart_Checkout</WP_Ajaxcart_Checkout>
```